# Add canvas to fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, webgl, fullpage.js

I'm trying to add a WebGL-script to a site with FullPage.js but it doesn't work so well (I just get a black screen). I have no idea what the problem is since both the WebGL-script and Fullpage.js work perfect separately. I was not able to add all the script to a jsFiddle but the scripts can be seen at this site http://www.scandinavija.com/index.html (I removed all the non-relevant script).

When I inspect the site in Chrome I get the following error: **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null at particles.js:6"** May that be the problem?

My instinct, however, rather tells me that the problem should be somewhere here:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fullPage.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/examples.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scrolloverflow.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>

    <!-- Particles (three.js) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/detector.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/stats.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/three.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/particles.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                verticalCentered: true,
                anchors: ['firstSection', 'secondSection', '3rdSection',     
                '4thSection', '5thSection'],
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- My canvas (three.js) below -->

<div id="canvas-container"></div>

    <div id="fullpage">
        <div class="section" id="section1"></div>
        <div class="section" id="section2"></div>
        <div class="section" id="section3"></div>
        <div class="section" id="section4"></div>
        <div class="section" id="section5"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
/* Reset CSS
 * --------------------------------------- */
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,
form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #000;
}
a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
}
fieldset,img {
    border: 0;
}
address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
strong{
    font-weight: bold;
}
ol,ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
caption,th {
    text-align: left;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:#444;
}
q:before,q:after {
   content:'';
}
abbr,acronym { border: 0;
}

/* START OF MY SCRIPT BELOW*/

#canvas-container {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this error because you try to access a property of an object that is evaluated to null.

*particles.js*

```
var container = document.getElementById('canvas-container');
//                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                       not found
var w = container.offsetWidth;
//      ^^^^^^^^^
//      eq. null
```

This is because your element `#canvas-container` doesn't exists in the DOM when the script `particles.js` is executed.

You just have to wrap your code inside a document loaded callback to ensure the element will be accessible :

```
$(function() {
  // particles.js code
});
```

You can also simply move your script tag at the end of your HTML file :

```
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/particles.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried to add the script to the HTML-file as you said and wrapped the code inside a document loaded callback but nothing changed. The screen is still completely black and the script doesn't run...

Comment: I tried too, and it works. You don't have to add a script somewhere, the script already exists, you just have to edit _particles.js_. Just add `$(function() {` at the top of the file, and `});` at the end :)

Comment: You don't have to wrap your function, just put your script tag at the bottom of the file instead of the top

Comment: Also you don't need `type="text/javascript"`  (Yea I know it was in the question, just passing on info, you're free to put if you want, it's just not need in any browsers).

Comment: Thank you but already know that, it's not the point here, I just try to solve the issue, it is not a code review :)